# Why are emoji symbols rendered with the padding on the right side?

Tags: html, text, symbols, emoji

I'm trying to implement emojis inside my rich text editor, Trix. There is basic HTML input element in which I enter the text.

I'm entering emojis as symbols - the same one that you can find on MacOS (by pressing the cmd+ctrl+space). It doesn't matter if I insert emoji with my custom implementation or MacOS native one, but the always have padding on the right side. Here's the image:

[image: symbol padding]

The selected text's length is only `1`, there's no space between emoji and letter 'H'!

How can I solve this and align emoji to center?

Comment: Could you provide some code please?

Comment: @CharleneVas I really don't have any significant code - I'm just displaying this as a plain text.